# Mi login me redigire a una direccion erronea fuera del subdominio

Tags: laravel

Lo que sucede es que estoy utilizando la autenticación por defecto de laravel, ya lo he probado en local y me funciona correctamente. Sin embargo al subirlo a producción en la dirección:

[www.municomas.gob.pe/Documentacion/index.php/auth/login](http://www.municomas.gob.pe/Documentacion/index.php/auth/login)

me redirige luego de tratar de ingresar:

[www.municomas.gob.pe/auth/login](http://www.municomas.gob.pe/auth/login)

No se si sea configuración del servidor o pueda corregirlo al hacer un cambio en mi proyecto. Espero de su ayuda.

PD: he cambiado las direcciones por defecto trabajando en local y no ayudan en nada, ya que al parecer hace el envió POST  esta otra dirección.

Answer (score 0):

crea una ruta en tu archivo de rutas que redirija a donde quieras, luego en el archivo Logincontroller.php y RegisterCntroller.php modifica el redirecto a la ruta que desees